# How to store inline file with active storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, rails-activestorage

I work with a third-party application and at this moment for upload an image with rails active storage, i have only access to inline data (like: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG....)
How to store then with active storage? Or convert it into blob?

avatar.attach looks to work only with blob or uploaded file from request / form

```
file = "data:image/png;base64,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"
```

```
ite = Item.find(item_id)
ite.presentation.attach(file)
```

Current working way by store tmp file for image:

```
ite = Item.find(item_id)

content_type = file[/(image\/[a-z]{3,4})|(application\/[a-z]{3,4})/]
content_type = content_type[/\b(?!.*\/).*/]

contents = file.sub /data:((image|application)\/.{3,}),/, ''
decoded_data = Base64.decode64(contents)

filename = 'img_' + Time.zone.now.to_s + '.' + content_type

File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/images/#{filename}", 'wb') do |f|
   f.write(decoded_data)
end

ite.presentation.attach(io: File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/images/#{filename}"), filename: filename)
FileUtils.rm("#{Rails.root}/tmp/images/#{filename}")
```

Comment: Maybe it helps https://medium.com/@sulmanweb/active-storage-as-attachment-in-rails-api-with-base64-decoding-f8362376d77c

Comment: Thanks you, i did it this way!